# Prevent multiple form submissions from same IP in specific time

Tags: php

I have the following script that creates 2 session variables storing the IP and the time a form was submitted. I was wondering if it's possible to display a message if the form is submitted more than 3 times by the same IP in the space of 60 seconds.

```
    <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    session_start();

    function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }

    $_SESSION['ip'] = getRealIpAddr();
    $_SESSION['time'] = date(DATE_RFC822);

// function to prevent multiple form submissions / bot

}
```

I realise this is quite rudimentary and not a failsafe, but I just want to put some basic abuse prevention and build from here.

Comment: I hope you know that two different sessions might have the same IP.. For example people connecting to your site from different browsers or people from an intranet connecting to your website.

Comment: That's a very valid point. I wonder if I can discriminate between the two somehow.

Comment: what you should do is not allow two or more consequent requests from one specific session and not on the basis of IP.